# how to redirect a pending firefox download to a named pipe?

Tags: linux, firefox, download, fifo

My router provides a live capture in an fancy web interface full of authentication and JS stuff. So if I capture the traffic firefox download a pcap file til I stop the job. I want to be able to see all traffic on the fly, also not to wait for finish download/capture job. I know wireshark can read named pipes so the question is how to redirect a writing file into a named pipe. I do not find any solution how to force firefox to write into one, and curl is not an option cause JS and authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `socat` for that. Make it read from the (partial) download file and send that to a named pipe, which you can then open with `wireshark`.

```
socat GOPEN:/path/to/download_file,rdonly,ignoreeof PIPE:/path/to/named_pipe,wronly
```

If you don't care about the whole file and want to start reading it from now, you could do something like:

```
tail -f /path/to/download_file | socat - PIPE:/path/to/named_pipe,wronly
```

Those two solutions above are for the question asked: *how to redirect a pending firefox download to a named pipe?*.

But you can, also do this, [as stated in wireshark wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes):

```
tail -f -c +0 capture.cap | wireshark -k -i -
```

Comment: That is nice. I played with `socat` a little but I could not find out how to shrink the buffers. `socat` has a _-b_ option but I did not notice any difference. All stuff comes in huge bulks and with some delay. That's not so easy to monitor.

Comment: That's another issue though. You only asked for the `file->named pipe`. Note that have lots of buffering between one and the other. Without Firefox, on any file, you will notice the pipe is fed almost in realtime as you append (I tested it), but if it is a download, it depends on when Firefox receives it from the network stack, then sends the data to the file, and when it is flushed. If you have other issues, such as buffering, considering opening another question after searching (buffering for processes on the other side of `tail` have many answers).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can simply use `tail -f` on partial download and pipe it directly to wireshark.